# How to generate indices like [0,2,4,1,3,5] without using explicit loop for reorganizing rows of a tensors in Pytorch?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, tensor

Suppose I have a Tensor like

```
a = torch.tensor([[3, 1, 5, 0, 4, 2],
                  [2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 0],
                  [0, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3],
                  [3, 1, 4, 5, 0, 2],
                  [3, 5, 4, 2, 0, 1],
                  [5, 3, 0, 4, 1, 2]])
```

and I want to reorganize the rows of the tensor by applying the transformation `a[c]` where

```
c = torch.tensor([0,2,4,1,3,5])
```

to get

```
b = torch.tensor([[3, 1, 5, 0, 4, 2],
                  [0, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3],
                  [3, 5, 4, 2, 0, 1],
                  [2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 0],
                  [3, 1, 4, 5, 0, 2],
                  [5, 3, 0, 4, 1, 2]])
```

For doing it, I want to generate the tensor `c` so that I can do this transformation irrespective of the size of tensor a and the stepping size (which I have taken to be equal to 2 in this example for simplicity). Can anyone let me know how do I generate such a tensor for the general case without using an explicit for loop in PyTorch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [torch.index_select](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.index_select.html#torch-index-select), so:

```
b = torch.index_select(a, 0, c)
```

The explanation in the official docs is pretty clear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Is there any advantage of using this method compared to the more conventional form of indexing like `b = a[c]`?

Answer (score 0):

Thinking for a little longer, I came up with the below solution for generation of the indices

```py
step = 2
idx = torch.arange(0,a.size(0),step)
# idx = tensor([0, 2, 4])
idx = idx.repeat(int(a.size(0)/idx.size(0)))
# idx = tensor([0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 4])
incr = torch.arange(0,step)
# incr = tensor([0, 1])
incr = incr.repeat_interleave(int(a.size(0)/incr.size(0)))
# incr = tensor([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
c = incr + idx
# c = tensor([0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5])
```

After this, the tensor `c` can be used to get the tensor `b` by using

```py
b = a[c.long()]
```

Answer (score 0):

I also came up with another solution, which solves the above problem of reorganizing the rows of tensor `a` to generate tensor `b` without generating the indices array `c`

```
step = 2
b = a.view(-1,step,a.size(-1)).transpose(0,1).reshape(-1,a.size(-1))
```